# Clarification about XmlReader.ReadSubtree method

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

i read the documentation on mdsn about this method, but i can't figure out the reason about the following behaviour:

suppose to have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project>
    <caseInformation Name="1">
        <field >aaaaaaa</field>
        <field >bvbbbb</field>
        <field >cccc</field>
        <field >ddddd</field>
    </caseInformation>
</project>
```

Now if you run the following piece of code:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        var name = reader.Name;
        if(name == "caseInformation")
        {
            using (var innerReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                while (innerReader.ReadToFollowing("field"))
                {

                    var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(innerReader);
                    element.Dump();
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

this will produce the following output:

```
<field>aaaaaaa</field>

<field>bvbbbb</field>

<field>cccc</field>

<field>ddddd</field>
```

if i change how i get the element using this instruction

```
var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
```

i get the same output. But i can't understand why.

On msdn it is stated that

> ReadSubTree() returns a new XmlReader instance that can be used to read the current node, and all its descendants.

and that

> When the new XML reader has been closed, the original readeris positioned on the EndElement node of the sub-tree

so this means that actually when i move the innerReader also the original reader moves?

Comment: "when i move the innerReader also the original reader moves?", yes what would be the use of staying put?

Comment: @HenkHolterman and what it would be the point on creating an innerReader then, if the operation on the latter reflects also on the original at the same time? I mean i know that when the innerReader is closed the original one would be placed at the closing tag of the sub-tree, but reading the documentation i would expcted that to happen,,,well when i close the innerReader

Comment: Well... it is tricky, and I'm not sure I understand your question anymore. The subtree provides a closed scope, stops you from reading too much. What is the problem you have?

Comment: I have not really a problem. I mean, i founded this because i made a mistake myself and used the second instance  and everything worked, howver that is no technically correct. I would have expected a different output. But since working with XmlReader is not easy at all, i was wondering what was causing this behaviour and if this can affect in any way my future work. Unfortunatly the documentation it's pretty bad and doesn't explain a lot of things

Comment: that's exactly what i am doing.

Comment: @DanieleSartori from the [docs for `XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx): *You should not perform any operations on the original reader until the new reader has been closed. This action is not supported and can result in unpredictable behavior.*  So basically your code happened to work despite doing something unsupported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acutally the new XmlReader returned by the ReadSubtree() method is not really a new XmlReader but a wrapper on the source XmlReader.

You can see that in the framework [sourcecode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs):

```
    public virtual  XmlReader  ReadSubtree() {
        if (NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString(Res.Xml_ReadSubtreeNotOnElement));
        }
        return new XmlSubtreeReader(this);
    }
```

This `XmlSubtreeReader` inherits from `XmlWrappingReader`.

And if you see the constructor:

```
    internal XmlWrappingReader( XmlReader baseReader ) {
        Debug.Assert( baseReader != null );
        this.reader = baseReader;
        this.readerAsIXmlLineInfo = baseReader as IXmlLineInfo;
    }
```

> so this means that actually when i move the innerReader also the
>   original reader moves?

Exactly, anyway it is not a problem because you are not supposed to call a method on the original reader until the "subReader" was closed otherwise you will get an exception.

A sample use of the method based on your sample code:

```
    public void ReadProjectInfo()
    {
        //...

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "caseInformation")
                {
                    ReadCaseInformation(reader.ReadSubtree());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReadCaseInformation(XmlReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            // if something raise an exception here
            // the main reader is not really affected by that
            // because when the methods ends, the "subReader" is closed
            // and then the main reader is set on the closing tag.
            // so the main XML reader can continue to analyze the xml stream
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(innerReader);
```

To:

```
var element = innerReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Output:

```
aaaaaaa
bvbbbb
cccc
ddddd
```

Comment: although this may be usefull in a context where you need only the content, the point of the question was to understand how the XmlReader and specifically how the ReadSubtree work